# How to keep postgres statistics up to date to encourage the best index to be selected

Tags: postgresql

I have a Notifications table with approximately 7,000,000 records where the relevant columns are:

```
id: integer
time_created: timestamp with time zone
device_id: integer (foreign key to another table)
```

And the indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX notifications_device ON notifications (device_id);
CREATE INDEX notifications_time ON notifications (time_created);
```

And my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count"
FROM "notifications"
WHERE ("notifications"."device_id" IN (
    SELECT "id" FROM device WHERE (
        device."device_type" = 'iOS' AND
        device."registration_id" IN (
             'XXXXXXX',
             'YYYYYYY',
             'ZZZZZZZ'
        )
    )
)
AND "notifications"."time_created" BETWEEN
    '2020-10-26 00:00:00' AND '2020-10-26 17:33:00')
;
```

For most of the day, this query will use the index on device_id, and will run in under 1ms. But once the table is written to very quickly (logging notifications sent) the planner switches to using the index on `time_created` and the query blows out to 300ms.

Running an `ANALYZE NOTIFICATIONS` immediately fixes the problem, and the index on `device_id` is used again.

The table is pruned to the last 30 days each night, which is why there is a separate index on the `time_created` column.

Can I fix this issue, so that the planner always chooses the index on `device_id`, by forcing postgres to maintain better statistics on this table? Alternatively, can I re-write the `time_created` index (perhaps by using a different index type like BRIN) so that it'd only be considered for a WHERE clause like `time_created < ..30 days ago..` and not WHERE `time_created BETWEEN midnight and now`?

EXPLAIN ANALYZE stats:

Bad Plan (time_created):

```
Rows Removed by Filter      = 20926
Shared Hit Blocks           = 143934
Plan Rows                   = 38338
Actual Rows                 = 84479
```

Good Plan (device_id):

```
Rows Removed by Filter      = 95
Shared Hit Blocks           = 34
Plan Rows                   = 1
Actual Rows                 = 0
```

Comment: I am fairly new to Postgres and had a doubt. Shouldn't we use a `JOIN` instead of a subquery, wouldn't that help ?

Answer (score 1):

I would actually suggest a composite index on the `notifications` table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON notifications (device_id, time_created);
```

This index would cover both restrictions in the current `WHERE` clause.  I would also add an index on the `device` table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON device (device_type, registration_id, id);
```

The first two columns of this 3-column index would cover the `WHERE` clause of the subquery.  It also includes the `id` column to completely cover the `SELECT` clause.  If used, Postgres could more rapidly evaluate the subquery on the `device` table.

You could also play around with some slight variants of the above two indices, by changing column order.  For example, you could also try:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON notifications (time_created, device_id);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON device (registration_id , device_type, id);
```

Comment: Because of the nightly prune task I hadn't created the composite (device_id, time_created), and I was worried that (time_created, device_id) would suffer from similar issues.

I'll play around and see what the worst case of (time_created, device_id) is.

Comment: Keep in mind that most of the time Postgres will only use one index per table to satisfy a query plan (not always true, but usually true).  So if you want an index to cover a `WHERE` clause, it generally should cover the entire thing.

Comment: The `(time_created, device_id)` index gets down to 10ms, still slower than an index just on `device_id`. `(device_id, time_created)` is 0.117ms where just `(device_id)` is 0.427ms.

Comment: OK...but I think the critical index here might be the one on the `device` table.  Not having any index on that table is asking for trouble.

Comment: There is already a unique index on device (registration_id) (and some other individual non-composite indexes) that make that individual query fast. Are you suggesting that the larger composite index could give the planner enough info to always choose the `device_id` index over the `time_created` one?

Comment: @JoshSmeaton Each table can potentially bring in an index.  I suggested the second index `idx2` so that the subquery on `device` can be fast.  There would be nothing at all preventing Postgres from using both `idx1` and `idx2` to satisfy the query.

Answer (score 0):

> The table is pruned to the last 30 days each night, which is why there is a separate index on the time_created column.

But, is that a *good* reason to have the index?  Does it matter if the nightly query takes a little longer?  Indeed, for deleting 3% of a table, does it even use the index and if it does, does that actually make it faster?  Maybe you could replace the index with partitioning, or with nothing.

In any case, you can use this ugly hack to force it not to use the index:

```
AND "notifications"."time_created" + interval '0 seconds' BETWEEN '2020-10-26 00:00:00' AND '2020-10-26 17:33:00'
```